# Firestore Rules allow only the owner of document to update it and others to update certain fields

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

Looking to create a firestore rule that only allows the document owner to update it or a different user to update only some fields.

Here's my rule

```
match /users/{userID} {
  allow update: if request.auth.uid == userID || (request.auth.uid != null && request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(["field1","field2"]));
}
```

It returns `Permission Denied On`

```
await _db.collection("users").doc(userID).update({
  "field1": field1,
  "field2": field2,
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look on this code. It allows others to modify only fields `bar` and `foo`

```
function isOwner() {
    return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
}

allow update: if isOwner() || resource.data.diff(request.resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(["bar", "foo"]);
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for ===> 1. The owner can update any field ===> 2. Others can only update only 2 fields.